# Using Event Data from S3 Trigger in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to craft a Lambda function using event data from an S3 trigger I have setup on a bucket. My first function works as expected and prints the event data. However, when I try and pull that event data into the next function the bucket name does not print which is what I expected. What am I missing here? Can I not pull event data into other functions to grab pieces of it?

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_upload_record = event
    print(s3_upload_record)
    
def print_bucket_name(s3_upload_record):
    bucket_name = s3_upload_record["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
    print(bucket_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `print_bucket_name` is **not called** at all. I think you should be using:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_upload_record = event
    print_bucket_name(s3_upload_record)
```